# How to show native jwplayer play button on iPhone

Tags: javascript, html5-video, jwplayer

I'm trying to make jwplayer show the native iPhone play button (see below) on iPhone, and a custom skin elsewhere. I've tried to use chromeless: true, but it didn't help (I still get the skinned play button). Now I'm stuck in jwplayer code and can't find my way through. Can you help me out?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid we fail back to the default iOS  tag so it is not possible to show our native play icon. However, in a future release we plan on adding out own mobile UX/UI, so this will be possible then!